# viewDidAppear/ViewDidDisappear knows the current transition has completed r not

Tags: iphone

I am pushing `emailChooserView` which contains the emails from the adressBook and sorting those emails based on the iOS sorting orderand displaying the emails. In only one scenarion(Delete some contacts from the adress book and change the sorting order. immediately click the button to push the emailChooserView ) app is getting crashed with the below exception

** Terminating app due to uncaught exception `'NSInternalInconsistencyException'`, reason: 'Attempting to begin a modal transition from to while a transition is already in progress. Wait for `viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear` to know the current transition has completed

How do I cure this? I have tried delays and other tricks but do not really understand how I'm supposed to use `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidDisappear` to help me .Any help gratefully received.

Comment: might be some view animation transitioning is in progress, are you presenting some view modally from viewDidLoad?